# For some reason Set<String> does not have "contains"

Tags: kotlin

Its init in the constructor and it returns set of the strings.

```
private val listener: () -> Set<String> = {
    NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
}
```

But for some reason I am not able to call `.contains()` function when I'm calling `listener.contains("package")`
It says
[image]

Comment: Your `listener` is a lambda-function, not a `Set`. You need to invoke it first: `listener().contains(...)`

Comment: @МихаилНафталь code sample?

Comment: he gave you a sample, right there `listener().contains()`, your call does not have the `()` after the `listener`. I'm just wondering if it was your intention for the listener to be a function, instead of an actual set. Did you write this code, or is it copied from somewhere?

Comment: Kotlin isn't like Java, where braces are only used for scoping; in Kotlin, other than for a few cases such as class and function bodies, they define lambdas.  So wrapping something in braces will change its meaning.

Comment: You might find it more _useful_ to write `private val listener: Set<String> get() = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listener` is a lambda of type `() -> Set<String`

in order to use `contains()` you need `listener`'s value which is `Set<>`

You can achieve this buy using `invoke()` as @Михаил Нафталь mentioned:

```
listener.invoke().contains("value")
```

or:

```
listener().contains("value")
```

[Invoking a function type instance﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance)